# The posts are not displaying which are saved in database in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

i am new to django and i am having trouble with retrieving my allpost (which we saved in database) in 'allpost' view that i have created in my 'blog' project. 
here are the codes-
views.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from . models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from . forms import PostForm

def blog(request):
    return render(request,'blog/blogpage.html')

def allpost(request):
    post=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/allpostpage.html', {'post': Post}) 
 # the posts are not displaying in this template #

def form(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.published_date=timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('allpost')
    else:
        form=PostForm()
        return render(request,'blog/formpage.html',{'form':form})
```

urls.py-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.blog,name="blog"),
    url(r'^form$',views.form,name="form"),
    url(r'^allpost$',views.allpost,name="allpost"),
]
```

formpage.html-

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
<head>
<title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="submit" class="save-btn btn-default">save</button>

</form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

allpostpage.html-

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for post in post %}

{{post.title}}

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

models.py-

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=500)
    published_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def publish_date(self):
        Post.published_date=timezone.now()
        Post.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py-

```
from django import forms
from . models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=('title','content')
```

those are my codes. please do check and correct it. again, the posts (which we saved it with form) are not displaying in 'allpostpage' template in 'allpost' view.Thank You

Answer (score 3):

In your view allpost. Instead of

```
return render(request, 'blog/allpostpage.html', {'post': Post})
```

it should be

```
return render(request, 'blog/allpostpage.html', {'post': post})
```

and in your allpostpage.html it should be

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for p in post %}

{{p.title}}

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```